# c++ override += with const reference

Tags: c++, constants

For a project I'm trying to create a vector class with vector function. I'm trying to add a vector addition function by overriding the += addition assignment. Because I don't want the += function to change the value to add I want to pass that value as a `const reference`.

My code:

**Vector2D.h**

```
#pragma once
class Vector2D
{
private:
    int m_x, m_y;
public:

    Vector2D(int x, int y);
    int getX();
    int getY();
    void setX(int x);
    void setY(int y);
    Vector2D& operator+=(const Vector2D&);
};
```

**Vector2D.cpp**

```
#include "Vector2D.h"
Vector2D::Vector2D(int x, int y)
{
    m_x = x;
    m_y = y;
}

int Vector2D::getX()
{
    return m_x;
}

int Vector2D::getY()
{
    return m_y;
}

void Vector2D::setX(int x)
{
    m_x = x;
}

void Vector2D::setY(int y)
{
    m_y = y;
}

Vector2D& Vector2D::operator+=(const Vector2D& toAdd)
{
    m_x += toAdd.getX();
    m_y += toAdd.getY();
    return *this;
}
```

But I get the errors:

> the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member
>   function "Vector2D::getX"

and

> int Vector2D::getX(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const
>   Vector2D' to 'Vector2D &'

I tried chaining the functions that return x and y to `const`:

```
const int Vector2D::getX()
const int Vector2D::getY()
```

but this won't solve the error. Remove the `const` from the parameter solves all errors and results in working code.

How should I change my code to make sure the value passed to the += operator can't be changed (for example by calling setY(100) on the object passed)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make `Vector2D::getX()` `const` as well. Otherwise you can't call it on an object you have by `const` reference.

Your attempt at adding `const` was applied to the functions return value, not the `this` pointer

```
const int Vector2D::getX()
```

Is a function on a non-`const` object that returns a `const int`.

```
int Vector2D::getX() const
```

Is a function on a `const` object.

This is one reason why it is often said that "a leading `const` is misleading".

Comment: I tried that see "I tried chaning the functions that return x and y to const:"

Comment: @SvenB, you didn't change the functions, you changed their return value. The placement of the `const` keyword matters.

Comment: I think I did not give a complete explenation of the problem. My goal is to pass an object that cant be changed (for example call setX(200). Or i misinterpeted your answer.

Comment: @SvenB, you can only call member functions marked as `const` on a `const` object. You didn't mark the functions correctly, that's what I'm trying to tell you.

Comment: @SvenB, Here's my point made: [A completely fixed example from your code.](http://ideone.com/xCSKPK)

Comment: Thank you it just clicked, what I did not know whas when a function is const it can be called by methods with a const parameter, BUT none const functions cant, therefore I thought the setX() would still be callable (changing the variable) of passed object , but because it is non const it cant be called.

Answer (score 4):

`getX()` and `getY()` are non-const member functions, which can't be called with const object. Since they won't modify any members of class `Vector2D`, you should mark them as [const member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#const-.2C_volatile-.2C_and_ref-qualified_member_functions), like

```
int Vector2D::getX() const
```

Note the position of `const`, which should be put at the end of the function declaration, means the function won't modify any members (except for mutable ones) of the class. `const int Vector2D::getX()` means the function will return a constant, it has nothing to do with the characteristic of the member function. In fact, return a constant build-in type doesn't make much sense, from the aspect of the caller side, it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I tried that see "I tried chaning the functions that return x and y to const"

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is : **Constant Member Functions**.

```
int Vector2D::getX() const
```

The const **after the argument list** in the function declarations indicates that the function does not modify the state of a object.

A const member function can be invoked for both const and non-const objects, whereas *a non-const member function can be invoked only for non-const objects*.

In your case, `toAdd` is const.